# Extended WebDriver and WebElement are not working

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebElement.sendKeys(java.lang.CharSequence[])" because "this.element" is null at com.org.automation.selenium.OSWebElement.sendKeys(OSWebElement.java:47)

package com.org.automation.tests; import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy; import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod; import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod; import org.testng.annotations.Test; import com.org.automation.selenium.OSWebDriver; import com.org.automation.selenium.OSWebElement; public class OSTests { public OSWebDriver osWebDriver; @FindBy(name = "q") OSWebElement elem; @BeforeMethod public void beforeMethod() { osWebDriver = new OSWebDriver(); } @Test() public void testXXX() { osWebDriver.get("https://www.google.com/"); OSWebElement osWebElement = new OSWebElement(osWebDriver, elem); osWebElement.sendKeys("XXXXXXX"); } @AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true) public void afterMethod() { osWebDriver.close(); } }

package com.org.automation.selenium; import java.util.List; import org.openqa.selenium.By; import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension; import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType; import org.openqa.selenium.Point; import org.openqa.selenium.Rectangle; import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException; import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement; import org.openqa.selenium.WrapsElement; import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Coordinates; import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Locatable; public class OSWebElement implements WebElement, WrapsElement, Locatable { public WebElement element; public OSWebDriver osWebDriver; public OSWebElement(OSWebDriver osWebDriver, WebElement element) { this.element = element; this.osWebDriver = osWebDriver; } @Override public  X getScreenshotAs(OutputType target) throws WebDriverException { // TODO Auto-generated method stub return null; } @Override public void click() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub } @Override public void submit() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub } @Override public void sendKeys(CharSequence... keysToSend) { this.element.sendKeys(keysToSend); } @Override public void clear() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub } @Override public String getTagName() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub return null; } @Override public String getAttribute(String name) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub return null; } @Override public boolean isSelected() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub return false; } @Override public boolean isEnabled() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub return false; } @Override public String getText() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub return null; } @Override public List findElements(By by) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub return null; } @Override public WebElement findElement(By by) { return findElement(by); } @Override public boolean isDisplayed() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub return false; } @Override public Point getLocation() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub return null; } @Override public Dimension getSize() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub return null; } @Override public Rectangle getRect() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub return null; } @Override public String getCssValue(String propertyName) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub return null; } @Override public WebElement getWrappedElement() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub return null; } @Override public Coordinates getCoordinates() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub return null; } }

### package com.org.automation.selenium; import java.util.List; import java.util.Optional; import java.util.Set; import org.openqa.selenium.By; import org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities; import org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException; import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverInfo; import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement; import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver; import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions; import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver; import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory; import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager; public class OSWebDriver extends RemoteWebDriver implements WebDriver, WebDriverInfo { public final WebDriver driver; public OSWebDriver( ) { WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup(); ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions(); chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-infobars"); driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions); driver.manage().deleteAllCookies(); driver.manage().window().maximize(); PageFactory.initElements(driver, this); } @Override public String getDisplayName() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub return null; } @Override public Capabilities getCanonicalCapabilities() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub return null; } @Override public boolean isSupporting(Capabilities capabilities) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub return false; } @Override public boolean isAvailable() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub return false; } @Override public int getMaximumSimultaneousSessions() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub return 0; } @Override public Optional createDriver(Capabilities capabilities) throws SessionNotCreatedException { // TODO Auto-generated method stub return null; } @Override public void get(String url) { System.out.println("Opening url " + url); driver.get(url); System.out.println("Application URL opened successfully " + url); } @Override public String getCurrentUrl() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub return null; } @Override public String getTitle() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub return null; } @Override public List findElements(By by) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub return null; } @Override public WebElement findElement(By by) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub return driver.findElement(by); } @Override public String getPageSource() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub return null; } @Override public void close() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub } @Override public void quit() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub } @Override public Set getWindowHandles() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub return null; } @Override public String getWindowHandle() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub return null; } @Override public TargetLocator switchTo() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub return null; } @Override public Navigation navigate() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub return null; } @Override public Options manage() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub return null; } }

Comment: Please reply someone.